# Print common lines between two files along with their line numbers in those files

Tags: text-processing, join

I have two files. I want to compare the content of one file with the other one. If there is a matching line between both files then print the line and its line number in each file. Example:

File 1:

```
ABC
PQR
MNO
XYZ
```

File 2:

```
qqqq
wewe
ABC
acdd
abcc
nop
MNO
```

Expected output:

```
ABC       1      3
MNO       3      7
..
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `awk` you could process the first file, store the lines (`$0`) and their corresponding line numbers (`NR`) (as indices/values) in an associative array (`l[$0]`) then process the second file and if a line is in the the array index print it along with the value of `l[$0]` and current line number (`FNR`):

```
awk 'FNR==NR{l[$0]=NR; next}; $0 in l{print $0, l[$0], FNR}' file1 file2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/sh

count_match() {
    grep -x -n -F -f "$1" "$2" | sed 's/\([0-9]*\):\(.*\)/\2 \1/' | sort
}

count_match file2 file1 > /tmp/$$A
count_match file1 file2 > /tmp/$$B
join /tmp/$$[AB]

rm /tmp/$$[AB]
```

These are the `grep` options used:

`-n` print matching line numbers
`-x` match whole lines only
`-F` match literal strings -- no regular expressions
`-f filename` read the search patterns from a file (in our case either file1 or file2)

Use `sed` to switch the order of the fields and drop the colon `:`.

`sort` the output.

`join` the contents of the two temporary files.

This demonstrates the usage and output of commands in the above example:

```
$ grep -n -F -f file2 file1
1:ABC
3:MNO
$
$ grep -x -n -F -f file2 file1 | sed 's/\([0-9]*\):\(.*\)/\2 \1/' 
ABC 1
MNO 3
$
$ grep -x -n -F -f file1 file2 | sed 's/\([0-9]*\):\(.*\)/\2 \1/'
ABC 3
MNO 7
$
```